# rsync: link_stat <PATH> failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: rsync

working with RSYNC on a command line project to sync my phone with my music folder based on a number of... options.  Not sure why it's failing, but here goes:

The command:
`sudo rsync -arvRn --progress --temp-dir=/home/test/ --files-from=/home/test/Scripts/phone-music-sync.txt  /home/test/Music/ /home/test/Phone/sdcard/Music/`

And the `phone-music-sync.txt` file:

```
    artist\ path/album\ path/
    artist2\ path/
```

I get the following errors:

```
rsync: link_stat "artist\ path/album\ path" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "artist2\ path/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Now -- not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I can `cd` into the directories just fine.  I can see the files.  If I get rid of the `--files-from` entry and replace it with an individual path, the `rsync` will work fine.

So:

1. The directories DO exist, and there are almost ALWAYS spaces in the path names.
2. There are files in the first entry and directories to recurse in the second entry of `phone-music-sync.txt`.
3. Because of something I can't quite figure out I have to sudo the command, because the phone mounts for only the `root` user to use.

Thoughts?  Been driving me nuts. :)

-Chow

Comment: This questions is quite old but still: The paths of your files listed in `phone-music-sync.txt` need to be relative to your source dir `/home/test/Music/`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647476/how-to-rsync-only-a-specific-list-of-files#comment58382454_30176688